# Implications of the IPython "Canary Method" and what happens if it exists?

Tags: python, ipython

The IPython source code includes [a `getattr` check](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/76481531fde0545439cfc3e86febdefd47aa5a43/IPython/utils/dir2.py#L65) that tests for the existence of `'_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_'` at the beginning of the `get_real_method` function:

```
def get_real_method(obj, name):
    """Like getattr, but with a few extra sanity checks:
    - If obj is a class, ignore everything except class methods
    - Check if obj is a proxy that claims to have all attributes
    - Catch attribute access failing with any exception
    - Check that the attribute is a callable object
    Returns the method or None.
    """
    try:
        canary = getattr(obj, '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_', None)
    except Exception:
        return None

    if canary is not None:
        # It claimed to have an attribute it should never have
        return None
```

And although it's easy enough to [find](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_%22+site%3Agithub.com+&t=ffsb&ia=web) other coders special-casing this name, it's a harder to find any meaningful explanation of why.

Given these two classes:

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Parrot(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print(attr)
        return lambda *a, **kw: print(attr, a, kw)

class DeadParrot(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print(attr)
        if attr == '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_':
            raise AttributeError(attr)
        return lambda *a, **kw: print(attr, a, kw)
```

It seems that IPython is using the existence or lack of this method to decide whether to use `repr` or one of its [rich display methods](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#rich-display). Intentionally thwarting the test in `DeadParrot` causes IPython to look up and invoke `_repr_mimebundle_`.

I'm writing an object that pretends all attrs exist. How do I decide whether to special-case this?

Comment: I have this same question. It results in odd behavior when implementing custom `__getattr__`

Comment: See [an earlier commit](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/9bf4fac39258adc331d864c5f04030accd642719) from where this code was moved for some more context: *"obj claims to have repr method... but don't trust proxy objects that claim to have everything*.